# Logback rolling file appender not working

Tags: java, logging, logback

Below is my logback configuration

```
<appender name="TIME_BASED_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\timelog.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">      
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\timelog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <maxFileSize>1M</maxFileSize>
        <totalSizeCap>10M</totalSizeCap>

    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

  <logger name="timeBased" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="TIME_BASED_FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
  </logger>
```

Code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Logger logger = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger("timeBased");
        logger.info("info");
    }
}
```

This code only prints on console, no file is created in specified directory. Folder has all write permissions. What is going wrong? Logback doesn't show any errors also. Please help. I am using windows7.

Comment: Where log config file ?

Comment: It's in project classpath. Getting picked up, i verified by changing encoder pattern etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace M to MB and correct fileName pattern
The example below works for me:

```
<appender name="TIME_BASED_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\timelog.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\timelog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
        <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>

    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder >
        <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: i tried your suggesstions, still nothing. Is this some system issue or something?

Comment: @Shades88 I don't know without logs. Check if there is write permission to that directory.

Comment: hey, M to MB and missing %i were the missing pieces. I pasted config you gave but forgot to correct log path. Thanks a lot, it works now

Comment: Ok. I was glad to help you.

Comment: See this example for how to configure rolling file appender with groovy config http://nimavat.me/code-snippets/logback-rolling-file-appender-example

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have specified the <file> parameter along with <fileNamePattern>

see "file property must be left unset/blank" in this link http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#renamingError

Comment: I was trying to create a RollingFileAppender and was struggling to understand the reason for it. Somehow i reached your answer and my issue was resolved.